# JavaScript tips in Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

Maybe somebody knows JS plugin for Sublime Text 3 which can show tips?
Like this:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0665.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be able to find JSHint through the package manager. 
http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/09/29/3-essential-sublime-text-plugins-for-node-and-javascript-developers/